# Creating a function that gets an array then gets the first number in the array and divides it by the next number in the array and so on

Tags: javascript, for-loop

So an array of [12,2,3] the function would make it equal to 2  ( 12 / 2 / 3 = 2)

[24, 4 , 3 , 2] would be 1 ( 24 / 4 / 3 / 2 = 1)

I can make these kind of functions for sum, multiply and subtract but for divide I just get lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use a reducer:

```js
const divideArray = arr => arr.reduce((result, value) => result / value)

console.log(divideArray([12, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: I tried and it worked
But how it works if result has no initial value. How we get a number in return since we are using result which has no value ?

Comment: `reduce` takes an optional second argument as the initial value. Since it was not provided here, `result` defaults to the first item in the array

Answer (score 0):

Just reduce the array to a number:

```
  arr.reduce((a, b) => a / b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method for such calculation.

```
arr.reduce(function(result, currentValue) {
  return result / currentValue;
})
```

```js
var arr = [24, 4, 3, 2];

console.log(
  arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a / b;
  })
)
```

Comment: I tried and it worked

But how it works if result has no initial value

How we get a number in return since we are using result which has no value ?

Comment: @PlínioHelpa by default the initial value  would be the first element.... or we need to specify as the second argument